# Error creating AndroidStudio projects

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I recently installed AndroidStudio to make applications for android and I could not do any project. From the first day I started it when I select "New Project" and later I select the activity "Blank Activity". I get all these errors:

[image]

Here are the logs:

[image]

Here is the preview:

[image]

I tried to uninstall AndroidStudio and install again and I tried to invalidate caches and restart it but appears the same.

Comment: What is the version of AS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem also came to me with 3.0+ versions but if you try AS Preview release: 3.2 Beta 1, you will not encounter that problem. If you don't like to update to a new one, you can do as below.

Go to your app theme(`res/values/style.xml`) and add below lines:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
  <item name="coordinatorLayoutStyle">@style/Widget.Design.CoordinatorLayout</item>
</style>
```

If above solution, also doesn't work,

try changing the library version in build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

If you increase the version, make sure to change, below two lines also:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
targetSdkVersion 26
```

`26` because I have decrease the version.

see [support libraries](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions).

Comment: I go to install the 3.2 Beta 1 to check if the problem disapears.

Comment: Nice, I installed the latest preview of android studio and works correctly. ¡Up!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're in a Google-sanctioned country. Like us in Iran. You better use a proxy like Hotspot Shield and restart Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Just install all packages of android studio .

Comment: I'm going to try it.

Answer (score 0):

go to build-> clean project-> rebuild